# Purpose and Usage of `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.class` when developing Native Plugin

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm currently building a Plugin to make use of native API's on Android and iOS.

I've written `MyPlugin` which implements `MethodCallHandler`. In my plugin project, I have an example app. This example app has a generated class `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.class`, which calls the static method `registerWith`. All of this is used as a one liner in the `MainActivity`.

I have several questions.

1. It seems that `MyPlugin` must match the name of the plugin project. IE - project is `flutter_tools`, my plugin must be named `FlutterToolsPlugin`, otherwise `GeneratedPluginRegistrant` will break. How is `GeneratedPluginRegistrant` generated?
2. What is the purpose of `GeneratedPluginRegistrant`?
3. What is actually happening to my plugin when it is registered?
4. If I want to use `MyPlugin`, can it be done so without the `GeneratedPluginRegistrant`? I wish to respond to lifecycle methods like `onActivityResult`, and it seems this encapsulation prevents me from interacting with the plugin directly in the `FlutterActivity`.
5. Can I interact with other native plugins from my own on the native side without having to go back and forth through Dart?

Comment: did you ever find answers to these questions?

Comment: Nope, and I've moved away from Flutter since I posted this. The tooling and support just aren't there.

Answer (score 8):

The GeneratedPluginRegistrant is automatically generated by a FlutterApplication in order to register plugins defined in your Flutter App's pubspec.yaml file. By providing an instance of PluginRegistry like *FlutterActivity* to the GeneratedPluginRegistrant#registerWith function you enable interactions between your Flutter Plugins and your Android APIs. 
see @[PluginRegistry Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/PluginRegistry.html)